# Flash Builder 4.6's default SDK is missing certain desktop classes

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have flex3 application which uses the following code.

```
import flash.desktop.TransferableFormats;
import flash.desktop.TransferableData;
```

When i use it in flash builder 4.6 it does not work and says "Definition flash.desktop.TransferableData could not be found"

What are the equivalent classes for above code in flash 4.6

Answer (score 1):

Use `Clipboard` and `ClipboardFormats`, the classes you found are from some AIR beta, many a moon ago...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to to fix this problem,

1. right click on project and open properties.
2. go to Flex Library Path
3. Select/Check the Include Air Libraries option.